# Error: b.replace is not a function (never got this before)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I must be doing something really stupid and I was wondering if anyone could help me figure it out.

**This is my controller** - I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) which is where Upload is from

```
.controller('main', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {

    $scope.shareLink = false;

}]);
```

**and this is my template**

```
<i id="share_mail" ng-click="shareLink = !shareLink" ng-style="!shareLink ? 'opacity:0.5;' : ''" class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
```

**error message**

```
Error: name.
    replace is not a function. (In 'name.
    replace(SPECIAL_CHARS_REGEXP, function(_, separator, letter, offset) {
      return offset ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter;
    })', 'name.
    replace' is undefined)
camelCase@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:2399:12
css@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:2842:21
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:2968:11
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:24962:60
forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:323:24
ngStyleWatchAction@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:24962:14
$watchCollectionAction@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:14110:21
$digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:14243:31
$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:14506:31
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:21443:29
eventHandler@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:3014:25
(anonymous function)angular.js:11606
(anonymous function)angular.js:8556
$digestangular.js:14260
$applyangular.js:14505
(anonymous function)angular.js:21442
eventHandlerangular.js:3013
```

Comment: Can I see your entire controller's declaration? This sounds like a problem with the minification array you can use for injecting dependencies into a controller

Comment: @bobbyz updated the question with the declaration

Comment: It is due to minification errors. Please post the code of your gulpfile / gruntfile.

Comment: @AvijitGupta i'm not familiar with gulp/grunt files :\

Comment: @bryan How are you minifying your code ?

Comment: @AvijitGupta i'm not minifying any code. the only minified declarations are angular.min.js and angular-ui-router.min.js

Comment: check controller syntax. Square bracket for dependency array is not completed.

Comment: @VishalRajole that was just an error in my part when posting to the question. it was always completed

Comment: Piece of advice - Don't use minified libraries.. Minify them in production.. but not in your development environment.. I don't think you'll find an answer to this one.. It doesn't seem very obvious (and the Angular error message is basically useless)

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan Could you elaborate? If it doesn't work now why would it work when my development is done?

Comment: With the minified version you get a useless variable name like `b`, in the un-minified version it would be something sensible that would help track down the error

Comment: Try using the non-minified version.. I used to use the minified version when I'm debugging (in my development environment) and it drove me mad! With the non-minified one, you can probably do a `console.log` before the error line to see what's going on. I have no clue why you're getting the error or what `b` in `b.replace` means in that context.

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan i've updated the question with a non-minified version. The error seems to be coming from my `ng-style` declaration

Comment: MUCH better now :) Can you format the error message a little better? Probably split them into different lines as they appear in your console

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your `ng-style` with [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and use it in this manner:

```
<i id="share_mail" ng-click="shareLink = !shareLink" ng-class="{'add-opacity': !shareLink}" class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
```

In your css:

```
.add-opacity {
  opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a tad confused why I was getting the error; but this method stopped it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line with `ng-style` to something like this -

```
ng-style="!shareLink && {'opacity' : 0.5}"
```

**or**

```
ng-style="!shareLink ? {'opacity' : 0.5} : ''"
```

Basically, you need to tell Angular that the expression inside the `{}` curly braces needs to be evaluated.

Here is a working example -

```js
var app = angular.module('test', [])

app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.shareLink = false;
    $scope.shareLink2 = false;

  }
]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div id="test" ng-controller="main">
    <i id="share_mail" ng-click="shareLink = !shareLink" ng-style="!shareLink && {'opacity' : 0.5} " class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    <i id="share_mail2" ng-click="shareLink2 = !shareLink2" ng-style="!shareLink2 ? {'opacity' : 0.5} : ''" class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I'd recommend reading up on Angular expressions, using tenary operators etc.